# What are these chair-like things in hotels?

Tags: hotels, identify-this

I've encountered them in most hotels but I can't figure out what they are for. Some are even mounted on the walls. What are they?

[image]

Comment: What's the name of this thing in English?

Comment: I love this question. I have always thought I am the only person in the world who has no idea how to use those things.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki: "Luggage rack".

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki you may also hear it called a "luggage valet" or "suitcase valet"

Comment: @Plebala - That is an interesting statement. Since this luggage rack is more prevalent in higher end hotels where there is little chance of bedbugs, I doubt that is the main purpose. As Nelson has said. It is actually to protect the hotels’ furniture from your luggage. Giving you a place to put your luggage besides their furniture. It is also a better option than the floor for the convenience of the guest. Any hotel room that even looks like it might have bedbugs is reason enough to change hotels, not just rooms. Regardless if they have luggage racks or not.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

These are for placing your luggage (presumably a suitcase) on. Easier to reach than if it's on the floor and you won't have to put it on the bed.

[image: Suitcase on a rack]

Comment: I have a couple of them in my home, for when I am packing and unpacking. They hold a suitcase at a convenient height, and fold up when not in use.

Comment: Not just suitcases, for lump travel bags they work wonders as well. I always suspected the idea comes from a cleaning lady, now they can still vacuum while your bag doesn't have to be moved. It also increases the chances of keeping the bag clean.

Comment: Suitcases are kind of rough on furniture... you don't really want a traveler throwing them on your tables and desk, especially the nicer ones with glass or nice wood finish. The ground is dirty, and the bed is going to get dirty. These things are cheap, doesn't take up space, and protects the hotel furniture and gives you easy access to the contents.

Comment: It'd be good if this answer actually says what it is, not just what it's for.

Comment: @pacoverflow Well I don't have a clue what it's called and actually the first time I encountered this was puzzled as well. Hey, it's a stand to put your bags on instead of on the bed.

Comment: @Mast "lump travel bags"?

Comment: @phoog Some people call them sport bags. Does that help?

Comment: @phoog In the US they're usually called a "duffel bag". I think that's a military term from the 1st or 2nd world war.

Answer (score 110):

As mentioned, they are for luggage. They are also typically required to receive a certain star rating by the different companies that release star ratings. For example, [the catalogue of criteria for Hotelstars](https://www.hotelstars.eu/fileadmin/Dateien/PORTAL_HSU/Kriterienkataloge/EN_Hotelstars_Union-Criteria_2015-2020.pdf) has item 115 for "Adequate place or rack to put the luggage/suitcase", which is required for 3-star ratings and above. If this wasn't included in each room then the hotel might get a lower number of stars.

Comment: @Melebius: I find it useful when answers that offer supplemental information demonstrate awareness of other answers, so as to help highlight what it is that they offer that other answers don't.

Comment: @CGCampbell I referred to the first sentence of the [original answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/revisions/153651/1), not the current state.

Answer (score 26):

As far as I know, this is designed so that you can put your suitcase or bag on it while you take things in or out of it.

This makes it a lot more practical than on the floor, and compared to laying your suitcase or bag on a bed, it has the advantage of not risking dirtying the bed, and being able to keep it there even when you use the bed.

Comment: Also a good harbour for bed bugs from the last people’s luggage. :(

Comment: Harder to climb for bedbugs than luggage on the floor though, so it all evens out.

Comment: @dragonspeed Not really, compared to the carpet, the mattress, the pillows, the duvet...

Comment: @Graham I saw it in 60 minutes once and here is an online article stating best place is in bathtub! https://www.apartmenttherapy.com/suitcase-hotel-bathroom-36634785

Answer (score 2):

As a comment by Schmuddi says, one term for this item is "Luggage rack"

Dancrumb offered "luggage valet" or "suitcase valet".

I've found that "Luggage rack" gets good results on shopping websites if you want to confirm.